# D3 stacked area with brushing - only first nested element shows

Tags: d3.js

I have an odd problem that I can't seem to figure out.  I have a stacked area chart with a smaller context chart below where I can brush similar to this: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367

The brush is working, but only for the first layer (I have left the clipping off as it is easier to see what is happening).

If I check the data in the console the brush function does only have that first key and if I change the order of the data the key in the chart changes so it is always whatever the first key happens to be.

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/goodspeedj/7Qzt4/

Here is the brushed function - the 3rd line in the function has the console.log statement showing the data only has the 'ABORTED' key (first layer).

```
function brushed() {
    main_x.domain(brush.empty() ? mini_x.domain() : brush.extent());
    //main.select(".layer").attr("d", main_area);
    main.select(".layer").attr("d", function(d) { console.log(d); return main_area(d.values); })
    main.select(".x.axis").call(main_xAxis);
}
```

I'm guessing this is something really simple - I just can't seem to see it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out.  I should have been calling selectAll instead of select in the brushed function.

This:

```
main.selectAll(".layer").attr("d", function(d) { console.log(d); return main_area(d.values); })
```

Instead of this:

```
main.select(".layer").attr("d", function(d) { console.log(d); return main_area(d.values); })
```

Comment: AMAZING thank you! I had exactly the same problem. I would upvote more if I could :)